# ¿Qué hice mal? El programa convierte los números arábigos a romanos pero el 6,7 y 8 (tanto en unidad decena y centena) no se imprimen bien

Tags: python, if, bucles

```
arab=0
arabmil=0
arabcen=0
arabdec=0
rom=""

arab=int(input("Número árabigo: "))

while arab>=1 and arab<=5000:

    if arab>=1000:
        rom=(arab//1000)*"M"

    if arab>=1000 and arab<=5000:
        arabmil=(arab//1000)*1000
        arab=arab-arabmil
    if arab>=900 and arab<1000:
        rom=rom+"CM"
    if arab>=500 and arab<900:
        rom=rom+"D"
        arab=arab-500
        rom=rom+(arab//100)*"C"
    if arab >= 400 and arab < 500:
        rom = rom + "CD"
    if arab>=100 and arab<400:
        rom=rom+(arab//100)*"C"
    if arab>=100 and arab<1000:
        arabcent=(arab//100)*100
        arab=arab-arabcent

    if arab>=90 and arab<100:
        rom=rom+"XC"
    if arab>=50 and arab<90:
        rom=rom+"L"
        arab=arab-50
        rom=rom+(arab//10)*"X"
    if arab >= 40 and arab < 50:
       rom = rom + "XL"
    if arab>=10 and arab<40:
        rom=rom+(arab//10)*"X"
    if arab>=10 and arab<100:
        arabdec=(arab//10)*10
        arab=arab-arabdec

    if arab>=9 and arab<10:
        rom=rom+"IX"
    if arab>=5 and arab<9:
        rom=rom+"V"
        arab=arab-5
        rom=rom+(arab*"I")
    if arab==4:
        rom=rom+"IV"
    if arab>=1 and arab<4:
        rom=rom+(arab*"I")

    print("Número romano: %s" %rom)
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando el número es entre 5 y 8 agregás los I correspondientes, pero luego vuelve a entrar en el siguiente if.  Si igualas arab a cero funciona.

Te paso el código (lo probé y funciona bien)

```
if arab>=900 and arab<1000:
    rom=rom+"CM"
if arab>=500 and arab<900:
    rom=rom+"D"
    arab=arab-500
    rom=rom+(arab//100)*"C"
if arab >= 400 and arab < 500:
    rom = rom + "CD"
if arab>=100 and arab<400:
    rom=rom+(arab//100)*"C"
if arab>=100 and arab<1000:
    arabcent=(arab//100)*100
    arab=arab-arabcent

if arab>=90 and arab<100:
    rom=rom+"XC"
if arab>=50 and arab<90:
    rom=rom+"L"
    arab=arab-50
    rom=rom+(arab//10)*"X"
if arab >= 40 and arab < 50:
   rom = rom + "XL"
if arab>=10 and arab<40:
    rom=rom+(arab//10)*"X"
if arab>=10 and arab<100:
    arabdec=(arab//10)*10
    arab=arab-arabdec

if arab>=9 and arab<10:
    rom=rom+"IX"
if arab>=5 and arab<9:
    rom=rom+"V"
    arab=arab-5
    rom=rom+(arab*"I")
    arab=0
if arab==4:
    rom=rom+"IV"
if arab>=1 and arab<4:
    rom=rom+(arab*"I")
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ya me funciona perfecto